# Движение блока по параболе

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, анимация, css-animation

С помощью jQuery animate делаю анимацию движения объекта, но нужно чтобы объект двигался по параболе, возможно ли это как-то сделать, задав лишь начальные и конечные координаты, а сама парабола генерировалось автоматически?

В примере условный код, отражающий суть вопроса:

```
<div class="block" style="left: 50px; top: 0"/></div>

$('.block').animate({
  left: 0,
  top: 100
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Вариант SVG

> возможно ли это как-то сделать, задав лишь начальные и конечные
>   координаты,  а сама парабола генерировалось автоматически?

Можно получить патч параболы, используя онлайн генератор [Quadratic Bezier Curves](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1116)

```
d="M40,106 Q192,17 371,107"
```

Первые две цифры - начальные координаты параболы, последние две цифры - конечные координаты.

Пояснения см. в листинге программы движения прямоугольника по параболе

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
 <!-- Парабола, по которой движется объект -->
<path id="t_path" stroke="dodgerblue" fill="none"  d="M40,106 Q192,17 371,107"/>

<!-- Объект движения - прямоугольник -->
 <rect y="-4" width="16" height="8" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none" >
  <animateMotion  begin="0s" 
   dur="4s" repeatCount="4" rotate="auto" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" >
  <!-- Привязка прямоугольника к параболе --> 
   <mpath xlink:href="#t_path" />
 </animateMotion>
  </rect>

</svg>
```

Если необходимо движение вперед и назад по параболе, то добавляется вторая парабола с наложением на первую параболу

```
 d="M40,106 Q192,17 371,107 M371,107 Q192,17 40,106"
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
<path id="t_path" stroke="dodgerblue" fill="none"  d="M40,106 Q192,17 371,107 M371,107 Q192,17 40,106" />

 <rect y="-4" width="16" height="8" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none" >
  <animateMotion  begin="0s" 
   dur="4s" repeatCount="4" rotate="auto" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" >
   <mpath xlink:href="#t_path" />
 </animateMotion>
  </rect>

</svg>
```

**Вариант анимации с добавлением градиентов**

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
<defs>
<linearGradient id="grad1" x2="0%" y2="100%"
  spreadMethod="pad" >
  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="skyblue"/>
  <stop offset="90%" stop-color="white"/> 
  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellowgreen"/>
</linearGradient>

  </defs>
 <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grad1)" stroke="none" />
<path id="t_path" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" fill="none"  d="M40,106 Q192,17 371,107 M371,107 Q192,17 40,106"/>

 <rect y="-4" width="16" height="8" stroke="teal" stroke-width="2" fill="none" >
  <animateMotion  begin="0s" 
   dur="4s" repeatCount="4" rotate="auto" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" >
   <mpath xlink:href="#t_path" />
 </animateMotion>
  </rect>

</svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо, как вариант, но не совсем то что имелось ввиду. Хотелось бы какую-то функцию, которая динамически изменяет значение координат по одной из осей во во время движения, и тем самым траектория получается параболой.